# encountered a problem while run php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homebrew, lib

% php artisan serve
dyld[2343]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.71.dylib
Referenced from: <1574B3CC-A9C9-3EAD-9D0E-9862223FF7BA> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.30_1/bin/php
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/72.1/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicuio.71.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
zsh: abort      php artisan serve

How do I fix it ?
help me

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to Composer?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you changed the PHP versions, try to do the following:

```
brew cleanup
```

to fix any ongoing issues with brew if that fails

```
brew upgrade
```

to update/upgrade everything, then run again cleanup